# DocumentDB Request charge very high for simple OR condition but very low for each condition separately

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I have queries:

1) `SELECT * FROM c where c.id = '0060f06e-260c-4dc7-9496-4a52e1a512c0'`

Request charge for it is 3 RUs.

2) `SELECT * FROM c where c.clientId = '0060f06e-260c-4dc7-9496-4a52e1a512c0'`

Request charge for it is 3 RUs.

3) `SELECT * FROM c where c.id = '0060f06e-260c-4dc7-9496-4a52e1a512c0' OR c.clientId = '0060f06e-260c-4dc7-9496-4a52e1a512c0'`

Request charge for it is **147 RUs**.

Is this normal behaviour? I don't see any reason for such huge discrepancy.

UPDATE:
in case 3), query returns 2 small documents (a few hundred bytes each)

UPDATE2:
I am testing against Azure portal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, i've got an answer from support team that might help others. Here's what they say:

> “This has to do with our current index where we cannot serve both ‘id’
>   and ‘clientId’ from the index at the same time. Basically ‘id’ is
>   considered a primary key and is indexed differently from ‘clientId’.
>   If either if the two expression is specified all by itself, then it
>   will be served from the index. However, specifying them together will
>   result on picking only one of them and dropping the other.”

The issue should be resolved in coming months (till summer).

Answer (score 1):

> Is this normal behaviour? I don't see any reason for such huge discrepancy.

If you mentioned Request Charge is RU, it is an **abnormal behaviour**. I agree with that you mentioned **it should have no such discrepancy.** I also test with azure portal on my side, but I can't reproduce it on my side. You also could test it with azure portal directly. If you still have question about Request Charge, you could create a [support request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request).

[image]

**OR**

[image]

For more inforamtion about RU please refer  to [Request Units in Azure Cosmos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations). The following is the snippet from the [Request unit considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/request-units#request-unit-considerations)

> When estimating the number of request units to reserve for your Azure Cosmos DB container, it is important to take the following variables into consideration:
>
> - **Item size**. As size increases the units consumed to read or write the data also increases.
> - **Item property count**. Assuming default indexing of all properties, the units consumed to write a document/node/entity increase as the property count increases.
> - **Data consistency**. When using data consistency levels of Strong or Bounded Staleness, additional units are consumed to read items.
> - Indexed properties. An index policy on each container determines which properties are indexed by default. You can reduce your request unit consumption by limiting the number of indexed properties or by enabling lazy indexing.
>     Document indexing. By default each item is automatically indexed. You consume fewer request units if you choose not to index some of your items.
> - **Query patterns**. The complexity of a query impacts how many Request Units are consumed for an operation. The number of predicates, nature of the predicates, projections, number of UDFs, and the size of the source data set all influence the cost of query operations.
> - **Script usage**. As with queries, stored procedures and triggers consume request units based on the complexity of the operations being performed. As you develop your application, inspect the request charge header to better understand how each operation is consuming request unit capacity.

Comment: Thanks for checking it! I didnt mention but yes, i also did my tests through Azure portal. I have created a ticket and we'll see what they respond. I will post their explanation here.

Comment: i've added one more response with explanation from MS

Comment: you're welcome! i am just not clear why are you getting expected, low RUs for the same thing? have you changed something with indicies?

Comment: I am also curious about that. I test it with documentdb without special configuration. Would you mind sharing your test document?

Comment: yes, me too. and i get same, high RUs result on both: azure portal and cosmosdb emulator locally. pretty strange. how many documents do you have in your collection? and how many documents do you have where `id` is different than `clientId`? (rough estimate, if its possible to tell)

Comment: Only 2 documents in the collections.

Comment: oh, that might explain your low RUs results

Comment: i can share whatever you need. please just clarify what do you mean by 'test document'? asking since i have a few different document types in same collection and collection has about 10k documents at the moment.

Comment: I agree with you that I get low RUs as I have less documents in the collections.